# Create an integer variable that can only takes values from a list with the cplex python api

Tags: python, api, cplex, constraint-programming, docplex

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel
mdl = CpoModel()
```

To create an integer variable between [0,10]:

```
variable = mdl.integer_var(min=0, max=10, name="variable")
```

How can I create a variable that only can take an integer value from a list? For example a variable that can only be 1,3,5 or 6?

Comment: For a simple solution that is not very elegant, what you could do is simply (for your example) declare the variable with a lower bound of 1 and an upper bound of 6. Then make a loop that goes through all values [1..6] and for each value, if it is not in your list [1, 3, 5, 6] add a constraint for it (e.g., variable != 2).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [set_domain](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/cp/docplex.cp.expression.py.html?highlight=set_domain#docplex.cp.expression.CpoIntVar.set_domain)

```
set_domain([1, 3, 4, 5, 9])
```

NB:

Here is a complete example:

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel()
dvar     = mdl.integer_var(0, 3, "dvar")

dvar.set_domain([1, 3])

mdl.add(mdl.minimize(dvar))

msol = mdl.solve( )

if msol:
    print("Solution status: " + msol.get_solve_status())
    print("dvar = " , msol[dvar])
else:
    print("No solution found")
```

You could also write

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel()
dvar     = mdl.integer_var(name="dvar",domain=[1, 3])

mdl.add(mdl.minimize(dvar))

msol = mdl.solve( )

if msol:
    print("Solution status: " + msol.get_solve_status())
    print("dvar = " , msol[dvar])
else:
    print("No solution found")
```